# Get folder name that appears when the device is connected to a desktop machine using USB Mass Storage or USB Media Device

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When Device is connected to the computer the name is displayed as folder of Device (e.g. SAMSUNG_Android) 
How can I get that name?

**Edited:**
I think we can't get that name. For some devices it is displayed, e.g. for Samsung Galaxy S3, but for others it is not.

Comment: Not to undermine your question but what could you use this for?

Answer (score 6):

the below method will help you :

```
public String getDeviceName() {
  String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
  String model = Build.MODEL;
  if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
    return model;
  } else {
    return manufacturer + " " + model;
  }
}
```

Comment: Scenario of what? I just connect device to the computer, folder appears with name SAMSUNG_Android. I need to get that name programmatically. Thanks

Comment: I think what Serg is talking about is the base folder name that appears when the device is connected to a desktop machine using USB Mass Storage or USB Media Device.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your referring to is how to get the Build Properties of device

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

`Build.PRODUCT` is probably what you're looking for. Usually that is displayed on the computer when you connect it.

It gives full Product name

Comment: I tried use Build class, but it doesn't hold information need to me. Build.PRODUCT is not suitable.

Comment: Can you edit your question. Give an example of what you need for a couple of phones. The only way to get data about the Phone is Build Class. So there's no real way to get more info. The answer will probably be some combination of the properties and an Example will help

Comment: I think what Serg is talking about is the base folder name that appears when the device is connected to a desktop machine using USB Mass Storage or USB Media Device.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the name which appears when you connect Android as a disk is the SD card volume label, at least on the devices with real (non-emulated) SD cards. It can be changed via dosfslabel when connected to Linux. There's no reliable way to read it. I think the best idea is to use Build.MODEL as default and allow user to change it manually in your application.